# ErrorException Array to string conversion

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

i am facing ErrorException Array to string conversion, I am new in laravel. please help me in detail if you can,please help me in detail if you can please help me in detail if you can please help me in detail if you can please help me in detail if you can please help me in detail if you can please help me in detail if you can please help me in detail if you can
This is my code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Redirect,Response;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Test;
use File;
class JsonController extends Controller
{
   public function index()
   {
      return view('json_form');
   }

  public function download(Request $request)
  {
      $data = $request->only('name','email','mobile_number');
      $test['token'] = time();
      $test['data'] = json_encode($data);
      Test::insert($test);
      $fileName = $test['token']. '_datafile.json';
      File::put(public_path('/upload/json/'.$fileName),$test);
      //return download(public_path('/upload/jsonfile/'.$fileName));

      $headers = [ 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', ];
      return response()->download($test, 'filename.json', $headers);

    //return response()->download(public_path('file_path/from_public_dir.pdf'));
  }

}
```

This is my jeson.blade.php

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  <title>Laravel Store Data To Json Format In Database - Tutsmake.com</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <style>
   .error{ color:red; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <h2 style="margin-top: 10px;">Laravel Store Data To Json Format In Database - Tutsmake.com</h2>
    <br>
    <br>

    @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
          <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </div>
    <br>
    @endif

    <form id="laravel_json" method="post" action="json-file-download">
      @csrf
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Please enter name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email Id</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Please enter email id">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="mobile_number">Mobile Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="mobile_number" class="form-control" id="mobile_number" placeholder="Please enter mobile number">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you try to initiate the array like this `test = [];`

Comment: its not working

Comment: your download needed a string but you give it an array maybe you should use `implode`

try `return response()->download(implode(" ", $test), 'filename.json', $headers);`

Comment: now this error is showing  The file "1618993601 {"name":"ABDULLA AL SHAHED","email":"alshahed.cse@gmail.com","mobile_number":"01628737935"}" does not exist

Comment: you can see my jeson.blede.php

Comment: where did that error thrown?